# function onHandleChange won't work until after I've selected both options in the select tag

Tags: reactjs

The function `onHandleChange` won't work until after I've selected both options in the `select` tag, then it start to work properly.I'm trying to render a chart based on which data the function gets. I'm curious to understand why this happens and where I'm making my mistake. Could someone please point to me where I'm making my mistake or if there's any mistake at all? I'm fairly new to React.js and programming in general.

This doesn't seemed to work until after I've selected both `options` from the `select` tag:

```
onHandleChange = (data, listDataFromChild) => {
  if(this.state.listDataFromChild === 'oneYear'){
    this.setState({
      data:oneYear
    })
   } else if(this.state.listDataFromChild === 'twoYear'){
      this.setState({
        data:twoYear
      })
   }
}
```

Here's the component from which the function onHandleChange gets it's data from:

```
export class SelectionBoxYear extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 'oneYear'
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }


      handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        },()=>{
            let { value } = this.state;
            this.props.callbackFromParent(value);
            this.props.onHandleChange(value, this.props.dataFromParent)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return( 
        <div>
            <label>
                <p>Select the year of the investment:</p>
                <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}> 
                    <option value="oneYear">One year ago</option>
                    <option value="twoYear">Two years ago</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Here's the full code: https://github.com/vtrpza/chart/tree/master/my-app/src

Comment: What do you mean, "only works"?

Comment: Please don't link external codes, instead create a [mcve] and clearly describe your problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19639044)

Answer (score 0):

From React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

In `SelectionBoxYear.js` file you need to put the `onHandleChange` and `callbackFromParent` functions in the callback of set state

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value
    },()=>{
        let { value } = this.state;
        this.props.callbackFromParent(value);
        this.props.onHandleChange(value, this.props.dataFromParent)
    });
}
```